# FluentUI DetailsList onColumnClick with React Hooks gives empty Items

Tags: react-component, react-functional-component, fluent-ui, office-ui-fabric-react

I am trying to create a DetailsList with sortable columns (similar as the example in the documentation here: https://uifabric.azurewebsites.net/#/controls/web/detailslist), but instead of a Class component I want to use a functional components and hooks.

The problem is that when the onColumnClick function is being executed, the "items" array is still empty.

This is basically the setup of my component:

```
const MyList= () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newItems = someFetchFunction()
    setItems(newItems);

    const newColumns= [
      {
        key: "column1",
        name: "Name",
        fieldName: "name",
        onColumnClick: handleColumnClick,
      },
      {
        key: "column2",
        name: "Age",
        fieldName: "age",
        onColumnClick: handleColumnClick,
      },
    ];
    setColumns(newColumns);
  }, []);

  const handleColumnClick = (ev, column) => {
    console.log(items); // This returns [] instead of a populated array.
  };

  return <DetailsList items={items} columns={columns} />;
};
```

The problem is that in the `handleColumnClick` the `items` returns an empty array. This is obiously a problem when you want to sort the items by a specific column.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, do you have an idea in the meanwhile?

Comment: I am facing same issue is there any update here?

Answer (score 4):

I assume the reason why the items array is empty is because the state got "stolen", have a look at this article: https://css-tricks.com/dealing-with-stale-props-and-states-in-reacts-functional-components/

To be honest, I don't understand why this happens, probably the `onColumnClick` is handled asynchronously?!

However adding a `useRef` hook solves the problem for me:

```
const MyList = () => {
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([]);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const refItems = useRef(items);

  const updateItems = (newItems) => {
    refItems.current = newItems;
    setItems(newItems);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const newItems = someFetchFunction()
    updateItems(newItems);

    const newColumns = // ...
    setColumns(newColumns);
  }, []);

  const handleColumnClick = (ev, column) => {
    console.log(refItems.current);
  };

  return <DetailsList items={items} columns={columns} />;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because columns are created only in the useEffect once and your state items are closed inside this onColumnClick method instance. The next render creates a new onColumnClick instance but all columns have the old one with enclosed old variables. The simples solution to that is to add in your code on each render (so directly in the component function) something like this:

```
columns.forEach(c => c.onColumnClick = _onColumnClick);
```

to reattach the current _onColumnClick to all columns.

Comment: This gives an error in TypeScript: "Arrow function should not return assignment". This fix is to add braces, like this:
`columns.forEach(c => { c.onColumnClick = _onColumnClick }); `

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is related to `closures`.
Your `handleColumnClick` column is the closure of the MyList component (function), and captures the `items` variable state at the time of it's creation.

The useEffect has an empty dependencies array, so it runs only once, assigning the `handleColumnClick` function to the onColumnClick property with an empty `item` array - it seems it is empty on first run.

The solution in your case could be moving your `newColumns` variable outside the useEffect hook, so that both `handleColumnClick` and `newItems` have the same instance of `items` on every render, like so:

```js
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const newItems = someFetchFunction()
    setItems(newItems);
}, []);

const handleColumnClick = (ev, column) => {
    console.log(items);
};

const newColumns = [
    {
        key: "column1",
        name: "Name",
        fieldName: "name",
        onColumnClick: handleColumnClick,
    },
    {
        key: "column2",
        name: "Age",
        fieldName: "age",
        onColumnClick: handleColumnClick,
    },
];

return <DetailsList items={items} columns={newColumns} />;
```

If you don't like the idea of recreating `newColumns` on every rerender you could also add a second useEffect with an `[items]` dependency to run only after the `items` is eventually available in the components state.